# Is there any possibility to replace MySql table name in query with result of another query

Tags: mysql

How to use select result of one table as table name in subquery. Is there any hack about that in MySql 5.6?

Comment: Please read this to learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the way SQL works is that all identifiers (e.g. table names, column names) and SQL syntax must be fixed at the time the query is prepared -- which is before it begins reading any data.

Therefore no data the query reads during the execution phase can change the table or other fixed elements of the query.

It would be like writing a function in your application where you wanted the return value of the function to determine *which* function to call.

The workaround is that you have to do this in two steps. The first step is what you're expecting to run as a subquery. It returns information you can use to choose which table to query in the main query. But you have to fetch this from the first query before you prepare the second query.